Pandas en python para buscar datos entre 2 archivos xls
Estoy cargando dos archivos xls en dos dataframes y mi intención es que cuando dos campos coincidan en ambas tablas (por ejemplo el "DNI"), que me copie la "Dirección" de una de las tablas a la otra. Lo que hecho utilizando iterrows, pero al tener que ir recorriendo todas las filas el proceso tarda casi un minuto. Estoy migrando el código que ya tenía hecho en C# con dos datables y allí apenas tardaba un segundo.
Mi pregunta es si habría otra manera de hacer que este proceso sea más rápido.
Lo he intentado con itertuples pero no me funciona. EL código sería este:
    Tabla1=read_excel_to_df(self.T1.text(),1)
    Tabla2=read_csv_to_df(self.T2.text(),'\t')
#añado columnas para que coincidan los campos con la Tabla3
    Tabla2['PROVINCIA']=""
    Tabla2['CCAA']=""
    Tabla2['PAIS']=""
    Tabla2['OBSERVACIONES']=""
    Tabla3=read_excel_to_df(self.lbT3.text(),0)
#creo un nuevo Dataframe donde guardar las filas
    tabla_Compara=pd.DataFrame({i[0]: pd.Series(dtype=i[1])
                    for i in Tabla3.dtypes.iteritems()},
                   columns=Tabla3.dtypes.index)
    #hago que las Tablas 2 y 3 tengan el mismo nombre de columnas
nomb_nuevo=Tabla3.columns.values.tolist()
    Tabla2.columns=nomb_nuevo
#recorro los dataframes buscando las filas a copiar y le añado los datos de tres columnas a partir de otra tabla
    for rowG in Tabla2.itertuples(index=False):
        encon=False
        for rowB in Tabla3.itertuples(index=False):
            if rowB.NOMBRE==rowG.NOMBRE:
                encon=True
                break
        if encon==False:
            for rowM in Tabla1.itertuples(index=False):
                if rowM.CIFNIF==rowG._3 and rowM.MUNICIPIO==rowG.MUNICIPIO:
                    A1=rowM._0
                    A2="ok"
                    A3="ok"
                    break
                elif rowM.CIFNIF==rowG._3 and rowM.MUNICIPIO!=rowG.MUNICIPIO:
                    A1=rowM._0
                    A2=rowM.MUNICIPIO
                    A3="ok"
                else:
                    A1=""
                    A2=""
                    A3="no"
            Tabla2[rowG.index,8]=A1
            Tabla2[rowG.index,11]=A2
            Tabla2[rowG.index,10]=A3
            tabla_Compara.loc[len(tabla_Compara.index)]=Tabla2.loc[rowG.index]

Esta última línea es la que no me funciona.

Para aclarar, ¿haces las substituciones en Tabla2 solo para las fila en las que el nombre no está en Tabla3?. Otra aclaración, tu condición en el if y en el elif del último for son exactamente el mismo... ¿te falta algún not por ahí?

Lo hago para que la Tabla2 tenga las mismas columnas que la Tabla3. Tienes razón me he equivocado en el if, para el elif sería  rowM.MUNICIPIO!=rowG.MUNICIPIO

También probé con el siguiente código pero la última línea me daba el error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (174,) (1565,) () 



tabla_Compara = Tabla2[~(Tabla2['NOMBRE'].isin(Tabla3['NOMBRE']))].reset_index(drop=True)
tabla_Compara['MUNICIPIO']=np.where((tabla_Compara['CIF/NIF'].isin(tabla1['CIFNIF'])) & (tabla_Compara['MUNICIPIO'].isin(tabla1['MUNICIPIO'])),"ok","")
tabla_Compara['PROVINCIA'].values = np.where(tabla_Compara['CIF/NIF'].isin(Tabla1['CIFNIF']) & tabla_Compara['MUNICIPIO'].isin(tabla1['MUNICIPIO']), tabla1['PROVINCIA'].values, "")



